# Perl module to handle request response

Tags: perl, httpresponse, perl-module

What is the best Perl module to be used in OO style to manage sending response to the client browser with headers, cookies, response codes, redirects. Should be standalone module not part of a framework, I use Moose and CGI::Simple only.

I know I can manually send headers and cookies but I want more control with easy interface.

```
print "Set-Cookie: $n=$v;$expires;path=/\n";

print "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\n";
```

Interface should be like:

```
$response->set_header(...);
$response->set_cookie(...);
$response->set_code(404);
$response->redirect(url);
$response->content(...);
```

I searched cpan.org about `response` and `http` keywords but did not get helpful results.

Comment: Consider using web-framework like `Dancer`, `Mojo` or `Catalyst`.

Comment: There's a decent list of frameworks available here http://neilb.org/2013/05/01/starting-web-review.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the most common [`HTTP::Response`](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [Plack](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack), which most of the frameworks use to handle exactly that. Though you really should use a framework.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really opinion based. So IMO, youre looking for

- the [Poet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Poet) - uses Plack::* and
- [Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason) what is using Moose for processing, e.g. query params handling and so on...

If don't want Poet, you can use Mason without Poet directly with Plack, but you loosing an great config management, session handling a much more...

The interface inside of components are like you want, e.g:

```
$m->redirect("http://somesite.com", 302);
my $user_agent = $m->req->headers->header('User-Agent'); #access headers
$m->res->content_type('application/json'); #set header
$m->print(JSON::XS::encode_json($data));
```

and so on..